# Remove a static block of text from file containing variable data

Tags: xml, awk, sed

I have a static block of text that I need to remove from a file created nightly from concatenating multiple files into one.  The text cuts across 6 line as one block and has a bunch of special characters like " , >  , and / .  I know I should be able to use `awk`, `sed`, or `perl`, but I can't get the escape of the special characters correct, either it errors or does not find the block.

The block is always this on the separate lines:

```
</channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title><![CDATA[Example]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[Example]]></description>
<link><![CDATA[https://www.example.com/]]></link>
```

I want to change

```
</item>
</channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title><![CDATA[Example]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[Example]]></description>
<link><![CDATA[https://www.example.com/]]></link>
<item>
```

into

```
</item>
<item>
```

it appears 8 times in the file that is created by concatenating multiple streams.

Comment: show us the result expected

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Please add sample input (valid XML, no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: is there something special/particular about this block or do you want to remove **ALL** blocks like `</channel> ... </link>`

Comment: This particular block, which appears multiple times, nothing else matches the </channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all blocks like `</channel> ... </link>` are to be removed
- OP has stated the file has 8x of these blocks
- actual data is formatted as in OP's sample inputs (otherwise, as Cyrus has mentioned, an XML/HTML parser may be more appropriate)

Sample data:

```
$ cat sample.dat
</item> keep this line
</channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title><![CDATA[Example]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[Example]]></description>
<link><![CDATA[https://www.example.com/]]></link>
<another_item> keep this line

<link><![CDATA[https://www.example.com/KEEP_THIS_LINE]]></link>

</another_item> keep this line
</channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title><![CDATA[Example]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[Example]]></description>
<link><![CDATA[https://www.example.com/]]></link>
</one_more_item> keep this line
```

One `sed` idea to find ranges of rows with the bookends `</channel>` and `</link>` and then `d`elete said ranges:

```
$ sed '/<\/channel>/,/<\/link>/d' sample.dat
</item> keep this line
<another_item> keep this line

<link><![CDATA[https://www.example.com/KEEP_THIS_LINE]]></link>

</another_item> keep this line
</one_more_item> keep this line
```

Once OP has verified the accuracy of the answer the `-i` flag can be added if the intention is to overwrite the input file with the results.

Comment: Almost, is removes the part of the block at the end of the file, not a big deal for me as I can re-add it, but that would be an issue for someone looking at this for a general solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how `part of the block` can be removed ... could you update the question with an example of what you're talking about re: `part of the block at the end of the file`?

Comment: the file ends with 
</channel>
</rss> 
this get removed with your sed command, even though the rest of the text is not present, I just readd those tags to the end of the file which works for me. 
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= 'NR==FNR{rmv=$0; next} s=index($0,rmv){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+length(rmv))} 1' remove file
</item>
<item>
```

The above wil work for any chars in the files since it's just doing a literal string comparison and it was run on these input files:

```
$ head remove file
==> remove <==
</channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title><![CDATA[Example]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[Example]]></description>
<link><![CDATA[https://www.example.com/]]></link>

==> file <==
</item>
</channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title><![CDATA[Example]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[Example]]></description>
<link><![CDATA[https://www.example.com/]]></link>
<item>
```

Comment: appears to only remove the 1st instance

Comment: @markp-fuso Right, that's all there is in the sample input. If the OP wants more than 1 instance removed they should include at least 2 in the sample input/output.

Comment: The text between instances is like 50,000 characters

Comment: @eliblaustein if you're saying you can't show 2 instances in your example because in your real data there's 50,000 characters between them - no, we don't need to see all of that, just create a [mcve] with a couple of lines between each block and show **that** in your question.